# Getting aggregate information from join table (ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :foo
   attr_accessible :awesome
```

Hi. I'm brand new to rails.  I need to get all the Foos joined with their count of bars that are awesome and not awesome.  Essentially this SQL:

```
SELECT foo.*, SS1.ac as awesome_count, SS2.ac as lame_count
FROM foo 
JOIN (SELECT foo_id, count(*) AS ac FROM bar WHERE awesome = TRUE GROUP BY foo_id) AS SS1 ON SS1.foo_id = foo.id
JOIN (SELECT foo_id, count(*) AS ac FROM bar WHERE awesome = FALSE GROUP BY foo_id) AS SS2 ON SS2.foo_id = foo.id
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this via the ActiveRecord magic (ala Foo.joins(:bar) etc)

I did try using find_by_sql, but I can't get the "awesome_count" and "lame_count" values back:

```
pry(main)> some_foo  = Foo.find_by_sql([ **THE ABOVE SQL** ])
pry(main)> some_foo.awesome_count
NoMethodError: undefined method `awesome_count' for #<Foo:0x007ad76450b70>
```

Is there a way to do this via the ActiveRecord ORM magic?
Is there a way to do this with find_by_sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query on Sqlite database :

```
Foo.find_by_sql("SELECT foos.*, ss1.ac as awesome_count, SS2.ac as lame_count from foos 
left outer join (select foo_id, count(*) as ac from bars where awesome = 't' group by 
foo_id) as SS1 on SS1.foo_id = foos.id left outer join (select foo_id, count(*) AS ac from    
bars where awesome = 'f' group by foo_id) as ss2 on ss2.foo_id = foos.id")
```

with sample data

```
<Foo id: 1, name: "foo 1", created_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:23", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:23">,
<Foo id: 2, name: "foo 2", created_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:26", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:26">,
<Foo id: 3, name: "foo 3", created_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:28", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:28">,
<Foo id: 4, name: "foo 4", created_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:31", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:31">]
```

AND

```
[#<Bar id: 1, foo_id: 1, awesome: false, created_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:00", updated_at: "2014-10-25 18:00:14", address: "bla">,
<Bar id: 2, foo_id: 2, awesome: false, created_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:14", updated_at: "2014-10-25 18:00:22", address: "bla">,
<Bar id: 3, foo_id: 2, awesome: true, created_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:26", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:26", address: nil>,
<Bar id: 4, foo_id: 3, awesome: true, created_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:31", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:31", address: nil>,
<Bar id: 5, foo_id: 3, awesome: true, created_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:34", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:34", address: nil>,
<Bar id: 6, foo_id: 3, awesome: false, created_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:38", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:38", address: nil>,
<Bar id: 7, foo_id: 4, awesome: false, created_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:44", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:44", address: nil>,
<Bar id: 8, foo_id: 4, awesome: false, created_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:46", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:44:46", address: nil>] Foo id: 1, name: "foo 1", created_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:23", updated_at: "2014-10-25 17:40:23
```

I was able to get :

result.first.awesome_count -> nil
result.first.lame_count -> 1

result.second.awesome_count -> 1
result.second.lame_count -> 1

Comment: I believe attr_accessible stops that from working and as the value isnt a true attribute of the model I was resistant to putting 'attr_accessible awesome_count' on the model.  In the end I separated the aggregate query from the find. 1. store the values onto attributes and built accessor methods for those attributes that access the cached values or if not present go to the DB and get the values.  Marking this a the accepted answer all the same.